# Set focus to next kendo grid row after enter key press

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I currently have a hierarchical Kendo Grid where I can edit some of the detail columns in batch. I have the autosync activated so I just have to lose focus of the cell I edit or press enter and it saves automatically.

So far this is working but what I need now is that when the user press enter in a cell, the focus change to next row, same column.

I'll put my context in words. I have a list of vehicles. I can expand those rows so I see a list of reservations for the selected car. After a given time, users will enter the mileage of the vehicle after every reservations. Let's say the vehicle had 10 reservations. When the user enter the first mileage data and then press enter, the focus change to the next row and he can enter the next mileage. And so forth for the 10 reservations. I don't really know how to achieve that and I figured I should ask for help.

Here is my relevant code.

Master Grid :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ParcAutoMvc.ViewModels.VehiculeViewModel>()
                .Name("gridListeVehicule")
                .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBoundVehiculeReservation"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.VehiculeID);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Marque.Description);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Modele.Description);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Annee);
                })
                .Groupable()
                .NoRecords(e => e.Template("<div style='padding:30px 0;'><i>Aucun enregistrement à afficher</i></div>"))
                .Pageable(e => e.Messages(mes => mes.Empty("Aucun enregistrement à afficher")))
                .Sortable()
                .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
                .AutoBind(false)
                .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(false))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(25)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("ListeVehiculeReservation", "Operation").Data("FiltreVehiculeReservation"))
                    )
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "small" })
        )
    </div>
```

Detail Grid :

```
<script id="client-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ParcAutoMvc.ViewModels.ReservationViewModel>()
  .Name("grid_#=VehiculeID#") // make sure the Name is unique
  .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBoundReservation").Edit("onEditReservation").Save("onSaveReservation"))
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Depart);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Arrivee);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Ville);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Endroit);
      columns.Bound(c => c.ReservePour);
      columns.Bound(c => c.KMDepart).ClientTemplate("\\#=Statut == 0 ? 'Annulée' : KMDepart == -1 ? '' : KMDepart\\#");
      columns.Bound(c => c.KMArrivee).ClientTemplate("\\#=Statut == 0 ? 'Annulée' : KMArrivee == -1 ? '' : KMArrivee\\#");
  })
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode
  .DataSource(dataSource =>
      // Load reservations
      dataSource.Ajax()
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(r => r.Id);
          model.Field(r => r.KMArrivee);
          model.Field(r => r.KMDepart);
          model.Field(r => r.Endroit).Editable(false);
          model.Field(r => r.Depart).Editable(false);
          model.Field(r => r.Arrivee).Editable(false);
          model.Field(r => r.Ville).Editable(false);
          model.Field(r => r.ReservePour).Editable(false);
          model.Field(r => r.Id).Editable(false);
      })
      .Batch(true)
      .AutoSync(true)
      .Update(update => update.Action(actionName: "Grille_Modifier", controllerName: "Operation"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("ListeReservation", "Operation").Data("FiltreReservation(#=VehiculeID#)"))
  )
  .Pageable(e => e.Messages(mes => mes.Empty("Aucun enregistrement à afficher")))
  .ToClientTemplate()
        )
    </script>
```

On top of my head, this is the relevant code for my problem. I know I will probably need to use javascript to set the focus but I can't figure out how. I managed to get the UID of the next row but I don't know what to do with it, or even if it's usefull for what I want to do.

```
function onSaveReservation(e) {
            var uid = e.model.uid;
            var idx = $(e.container).index();
            var sender = e.sender;

            dataView = this.dataSource.view();

            for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
                if (dataView[i].uid == uid) {
                    var vehiculeID = dataView[i].VehiculeID
                    if (dataView[i + 1] != null)
                    {
                        var nextUid = dataView[i + 1].uid;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

I would be very thankfull of everyone who can help me with my problem. Please tell me if I was not clear in what I want to do, english is not my first language. Don't hesitate to ask for more sample of my code if you need anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but I found out how to do what I wanted and I figured I'll let people know in case it helps anyone in the future.

I let out a lot of code and kept only what is relevent to focus the next cell of the same column of the next row. If anyone need more, feel free to ask.

```
//In my onSave Event I assign the next cell based on the selected car and row
gridReservation = $("#grid_" + vehiculeID); 
rowEdited = gridReservation.data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + e.model.uid + "']").index();
nextRow = rowEdited + 1;
nextCell = '#grid_' + vehiculeID + ' tbody tr:eq(' + nextRow + ') td:eq(6)' //In my case I needed the 6th column;

//Then on my onDataBound event of my detail grid I set which cell I need to be editing
var theCell = $(nextCell);
gridReservation.data('kendoGrid').editCell(theCell);
```

Hope it helps anyone